# Postfix not detecting hostname or domain

Tags: postfix

I'm having a problem with Postfix (on Centos 6.5) whereby I have to set myhostname explicitly in main.cf, otherwise local mail is relayed through the relay host.

According to the Postfix main.cf: "The default is to use the fully-qualified domain name from gethostname()."

My /etc/hosts file is:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.0.0.3        server123.company.org server123
```

hostname and hostname -f return correctly.

How can I troubleshoot why this isn't working?

Answer (score 4):

Solved... problem was incorrect entry in /etc/sysconfig/network for HOSTNAME.  This was set to the short name instead of the FQDN.  Fixed the entry in that file and restarted the network service.

Was able to check that gethostname() retrieves the full hostname via the following test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX];

    if (gethostname(hostname, sizeof hostname) == 0)
        puts(hostname);
    else
        perror("gethostname");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to see what the result of `gethostname()` would be and this helped me. On macOS I was getting this error: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'HOST_NAME_MAX'`. Per https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/developers-list/2008-May/002154.html, I switched  `HOST_NAME_MAX` to `_POSIX_HOST_NAME_MAX` and got it to work.